# Administrator page 404 not found

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, .htaccess-configuration, apache, nginx

I can't access administrator's page; it returns 404 error not found. Although when I rename `.htaccess` to `htaccess.txt`, admin page works, **but** the whole site returns 404 error not found. When I rename it back to `.htaccess`, the website pages work, but not the admin page.

I am using Joomla 3 and I am using an extra login layer (from a plugin, but can't remember its name) for the Joomla administration panel.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Do you have SEF URL's enabled in the Joomla Global Configuration?

Comment: Remove that extra login layer and try again.

Comment: @Lodder Yes I have SEF URL's enabled.

Comment: What happens if you disable SEF URL's?

Comment: @Lodder I've found the problem but I don't know how to fix it. I've downloaded Admin Tools Plugin -> https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/admin-tools.html
I've downloaded it for an extra protection layer, though it seems when I disable this plugin, everything works fine. I think the problem is that this Admin Tools is using Non SEF URL's. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment, but one of those security plugins that Lodder mentioned is kSecure Login Protect. Try look for that in the extensions database and disable it from there.

Comment: I am having the same problem, no access to admin main page - however can access any subpage without getting 404'd

Comment: also using akeeba - disabled it to no effect. this issue occurs on 2 out of 3 akeeba'd sites. the one with no problem is a fresh install, the problem ones are old, have been moved using akeeba, and many updates applied.

Answer (score 4):

If your admin area works widthout .htaccess its possible your joomla config has rewrite option enable. You can try edit your configuration.php file and change the status directly in configuration file:

```
$sef_rewrite = '0';
$sef = '0';
$sef_suffix = '0';
```

Comment: This worked for me but then it messes up my URL's

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and found a solution.

Disable the following items:

**Cache**

```
public $ caching = '';
public $ cache_handler = 'file'; # (replace memcache, per file)
public $ cachetime = '1600';
```

**Memcache**

```
public $ memcached_persist = '0'; # I was in '1'
```

**Live Site**

```
public $ live_site = ''; # (remove the full domain name)
```

**Gzip**

```
public $ gzip = '0'; # (disable, after running ... test the activation)
```

**Sef**

```
# (Disable as below, after running test enable)

public $ sef = '0';
public $ sef_rewrite = '0';
public $ sef_suffix = '0';
```

**In case of error 404 for other pages, possibly the SEF is enabled.**

1. Check the .htacess (Rewrite enabled)
2. Activate Rewrite

   ```
   $ cd / etc / apache2 / mods-available
   a2enmod rewrite
   ```

**For SEF in NGINX with PHP-FPM**
Put in domain configuration (etc / nginx / sites-available / SITE.conf)

```
 server {
     listen ## IP ### or *: 80;
     server_name MYSITE.com www.MYSITE.com;
     root / home / MYSITE / public_html;
     index.php index.html index.htm; #### VERIFY THIS ORDER
     access_log /var/log/MYSITE.com_access_log;
     error_log /var/log/MYSITE.com_error_log;
     fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI / 1.1;
     fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
     fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $ query_string;
     fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $ request_method;
     fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $ content_type;
     fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $ content_length;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME / home / MYSITE / public_html $                            
     fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $ fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $ request_uri;
     fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $ document_uri;
     fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT / home / MYSITE / public_html;
     fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $ server_protocol;
     fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $ remote_addr;
     fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $ remote_port;
     fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $ server_addr;
     fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $ server_port;
     fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $ server_name;
     fastcgi_param HTTPS $ https;
     ##-> see that it is uncommented ## location ~ \ .php $ {
     ##-> uncommented ## try_files $ uri = 404;
     ## -> uncommented ## fastcgi_pass unix: /var/php-nginx/172882919829029351.sock/socket;
     location / {
         try_files $ uri /index.php;
     }
     location ~ \ .php $ {
         try_files $ uri = 404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^ (. + \. php) (/.+) $;
         fastcgi_pass localhost: 8001;
         fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;
         -> configuration for SSL HTS #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age = 31536000; includeSubDomains" always;   
     }
     location ~ \ .user \ .ini $ {
         deny all;
     }
     listen ### IP or *: 443 ssl;
     ssl_certificate /home/mysite/ssl.cert;
     ssl_certificate_key /home/mysite/ssl.key;
     fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried to tighten up the formatting/tabbing.  Please review my edit, and re-edit if I have damaged anything in your post.  (Everyone hopes their posts are helpful, but "Hope this helps" is an unnecessary signoff, so I have removed it.)

Answer (score 0):

Does that plugin by any chance add a token to access the admin? Like you need to add ?foo=bar to the URL to get access. Then it's working as intended.

You can disable that plugin by simply renaming the folder using FTP or by changing the state of it in the database (#__extension table).

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin Tools** in the Joomla backend, then go to the **SEO and Link Tools** section.

In there, there will be 2 options:

- Enable link migration
- Convert all links to HTTPS when site is accessed over SSL

Try disabling both of these if they are enabled.

Comment: They were already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is in the file .htaccess

Delete the line:

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

and save

go in your browser to: joomla/administrator  and al work again!

Comment: Hi @Jhonny Barrios, can u explain why the above fixes the issue, it fixed the issue for me as well,but unsure the reason it fixed the issue

Comment: This worked for me but then it broke my interior pages

Answer (score 0):

In configuration.php, set `public $live_site = '';` (only when working on localhost).
I've been facing this problem myself repeatedly, for years literally, every time forgetting this old trick.